# Accents only work half the time

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, special-characters

I've been having a very odd issue on an HP pavilion laptop running Windows 10 1903.

When I press the accent keys (´/` and ~/^), followed by a letter ("a", for example), some times an accented letter will be  written, but most times an unaccented letter will be written. What happens at any given keypress seems completely random.
Here is a sample for each accent key:

```
áááaaaaaaaaááaá
aaàaààaaàaaaaaa
aããããaaãããaaaaã
aaâaaâaââââaaaa
```

I initially thought this might be an hardware issue, but if I press the accent keys twice it will always print the accent character twice by itself (normal behaviour). Additionally:

- Only the Portuguese language is installed, with the Portuguese keyboard selected;
- I have tried re-installing Windows multiple times, and the issue persists.

I am stumped, how is this possible? What could cause this and how could this be fixed?

Comment: Have you tested another keyboard (if you have one available)? Have you tried using the On-Screen Keyboard to manually press the individual keys with your mouse? Also, you can use a key tracer such as UIforETW to track exactly what's being registered as pressed by Windows. Also, does this happen in every application or just a specific one?